# Python: extracting comments from a css file

Tags: python, css, regex, comments, text-processing

I would like to extract the first comment block of a CSS file which is like this :

```
/*
author : name
uri : link
etc
*/
```

without extracting the other comments

```
/* header */
/* footer */
```

So I tried this :

```
print re.findall(r'\/\*(.*)\*\/', cssText )
```

this gave me all the other comments except the block I need.  so I changed it into this, to be more precise :

```
print re.findall(r'\/\*\n(.*)^\*\/', cssText )
```

and the result was nothing :

```
[]
```

Do you have suggestions? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
css = """
/*
author : name
uri : link
etc
*/

bla bla bla. Blah blah
x: 10;
color: red;

/* header */
/* footer */
"""

import re

pat = r'\/\*([\S\s]*?)\*\/'

print re.findall(pat, css)
print re.search(pat, css).group()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the first comment you can simply only use the first result:

```
print re.findall(r'\/\*(.*)\*\/', cssText )[0]
```

You can also use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.search) which searches for the first matching occurrence:

```
print re.search(r'\/\*(.*)\*\/', cssText )
```

Comment: Working with `[0]` gave me the first comments just after the block I need. 
The other one works with `.group()` and it give the same result as the first.

Answer (score 1):

When you match multi line string, you need to make . match \n too:

```
print re.findall(r'\/\*\n(.*?)\*\/', cssText, re.S)
```

see: 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S

Comment: Ups, I messed up quotation /* instead \\*. Check now, it should work.